# Android - loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: java, android, webview

I am using webview to display the html page on screen. My html page contains image tag where all images are stored in assets folder of android having subfolder

> > assets/userfile/images/01.jpg
> >     assets/userfile/images/04.jpg

I am loading the html using following code in java class

```
String htmlFilename = "sample.html";
AssetManager mgr = getBaseContext().getAssets();
try {
        InputStream in = mgr.open(htmlFilename, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);
        String htmlContentInStringFormat = StreamToString(in);
        htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset", htmlContentInStringFormat, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And My html code is

```
<p><img alt="Comet 67P" src="/userfile/images/01.jpg" style="float:right; height:239px; width:300px" /></p>

<p><img alt="Comet 67P" src="/userfile/images/04.jpg" style="float:right; height:239px; width:300px" /></p>
```

but images are not getting loaded in webview.

Instead, if I replace in java code

```
 htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/userfile/images/", htmlContentInStringFormat, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

and if changed html as

```
<p><img alt="Comet 67P" src="01.jpg" style="float:right; height:239px; width:300px" /></p>

<p><img alt="Comet 67P" src="04.jpg" style="float:right; height:239px; width:300px" /></p>
```

then it works properly..
"/userfile/image/" is dynamically generated from the server so I don't want to put it as a baseURL

Comment: have you tried using the relative uri such as `userfile/image...` instead of `/userfile/image...`?

Comment: /userfile/image/01.jpg is the src of image when i'm getting the html code from server so can not able to change it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some thing like this:

```
htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContentInStringFormat, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

<p><img alt="Comet 67P" src="file:///android_asset/userfile/images/01.jpg" style="float:right; height:239px; width:300px" /></p>

<p><img alt="Comet 67P" src="file:///android_asset/userfile/images/04.jpg" style="float:right; height:239px; width:300px" /></p>
```

Comment: hi Emre : I tried the same and its working as well.. but due to some project requirement in html src for img is like "/userfile/images/01.jpg" this only.. we can not change it to complete url  file:///android_asset/userfile/images/01.jpg

Comment: due to some restrictions I can not do 
 <p><img alt="Comet 67P" src="file:///android_asset/userfile/images/04.jpg" style="float:right; height:239px; width:300px" /></p>

or

htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/userfile/images/", htmlContentInStringFormat, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

I have to provide the base URL as ""file:///android_asset"

Comment: Okay so you keep html same and edit loadDataWithBaseURL like this; 
htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "file:///android_asset" + htmlContentInStringFormat, "text/html", "utf-8", null); @AjinkyaJawalkar

Comment: absolutely not working.. 2nd parameter of this method is HTML string so if we do "file:///android_asset" + htmlContentInStringFormat, it takes "file:///android_asset" as a part of html and display this string on Screen

Comment: @AjinkyaJawalkar I can recommend you a library named 'jsoup'. It is used for parsing a HTML text. You just need to connect to the url of your html document and select("p"). Example: 

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

Element p = doc.select("p").first();
String src = p.attr("src");

And then use this src as htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset" + src, null, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Comment: is it possible to replace the attributes of image tag in java code before loading the html to the webview ?